Is disable timer_migration recommended for Realtime linux kernel?
I am executing cyclic test on Linux realtime kernel and observing high latencies. But when I disable timer migration, I am able to observe latencies in expected range.
Is this tuning recommened to do? Will it have any adverse impact?
Command for timer migration:
echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/timer_migration
Running cyclic test on 3 cores which have no_hz_full enabled to make it tickless. The kernel is realtime with PREEMPT_RT patch.
mkdir /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset/core1-3/
echo 0 > /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset/core1-3/cpuset.mems
echo 1-3 > /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset/core1-3/cpuset.cpus
cgexec -g cpuset:core1-3 cyclictest -a 1-3 -t 3 -m -l 100000000 -i 1000 -p 99 -h 800

"The kernel is realtime with PREEMPT_RT patch." - It is never correct to say the Linux kernel is Real Time. PREEMPT_RT patch makes Linux kernel to expose behavior closer to the one of Real Time systems. But that patch doesn't make the Linux kernel to be one of Real Time systems.

Ubuntu more properly calls it the low-latency kernel. See here for the changes they make https://hatchjs.com/ubuntu-22-04-low-latency-kernel/

I agree I framed it in a wrong way. I am using Linux kernel with preempt_rt patch. But is timer_migration a recommended option to improve latencies?
